# How to use Auth0's session management features in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, timeout, token, auth0

I am using Auth0's `inactivity timeout` and `require login after` capabilities in a Rails 6 app.
I have followed the documentation in setting up the sample app and providing values for these fields to 1 minutes (for testing purposes).

When I sign in locally, and wait for the timeout to expire, I am still logged in when I refresh the page.

I have followed this [link](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/sessions/configure-session-lifetime-settings) to set the timeout values.

I expected the refresh to redirect me to the login page after the 1 minute of being idle.

I'm not sure if I am missing some kind of Rails or Auth0 setting which enables this feature, or if there is more code using the request object when the user logs in with Auth0?

Any feedback is appreciated, thank you.